# If above critical temperature, no gas molecules can be converted back to the liquid state, then what about the molecules boiling up before that?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

What is so different between the molecules that have already evaporated but below the critical temperature than those that exist after reaching the critical point?
If there are gases above critical temperatures that cannot be converted back to liquid, are there any critical liquids in the sense that they cannot be frozen back to solids?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on several misunderstandings about vapor-liquid equilibrium and the critical point. To understand what is going on we can look at the $PV$ graph of a pure fluid. The supercritical region is defined by the conditions $T>T_C$ and $P>P_C)$.

[image]

- **Below the critical point:** Cooling gas $B$ under constant temperature will make it liquid ($A$). During this process we will observe a *phase transition* during which *both* phases, saturated vapor at $V$ and saturated liquid at $L$ are present. As cooling continues all the vapor condenses and with further cooling the state goes to $A$. (Notice that in this example the initial state is at $T>T_C$ but is still undergoes a phase transition upon isobaric cooling because its pressure is below critical.)
- **Above the critical point:** Cooling state $F$ under constant temperature will bring it to state $E$. There is *no* phase transition because line $FE$ does not intersect the vapor/liquid boundaries (bell shaped curve). State $F$  is gas-like: it has low density and is fairly compressible (its isotherm has a gentle slope. State $E$ is liquid like: it has low density and is far less compressible (its isotherm is steep).

The correct thing to say about supercritical states is that neither isobaric cooling nor isothermal compression go through a *phase transition*.

You can see now that the question

> What is so different between the molecules that have already evaporated but below the critical temperature than those that exist after reaching the critical point?

is meaningless. There is no such thing as "molecules that have already evaporated but below the critical temperature" because the thermodynamic state does not depend on its history.

The following statement is also incorrect:

> if there are gases above critical temperatures that cannot be converted back to liquid

If you are at a supercritical state, say $F$, there is always a path (actually an infinite number of paths) to reach the liquid at $A$ through a series of heating/cooling and expansion/compression. For example, cool $A$ at constant pressure to $E$, then compress at constant temperature till you reach $A$. So it is not true that a supercritical fluid cannot be turned into a liquid again.

This also means that your final question,

> are there any critical liquids in the sense that they cannot be frozen back to solids?

has no basis. We can go from *any* state on the $PV$ graph to any other (this $PV$ does not show the liquid/solid transition, which would be to the left of the plot). Being supercritical does not lock the system to supercritical states only.